# Simplification of matrix operation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I’m struggling on how can I simplify the following equation such that I could calculate $\Psi^{-1}$ only once.

$$a^T\Psi^{-1}a - b^T\Psi^{-1}b$$.

Since $\Psi^{-1}$ is the inverse of a correlation matrix, $a$ and $b$ are vectors of same lengths that dimension of the correlation matrix.

Any hint on how can I simplify that?

Comment: The fact that $\Psi^{-1}$ is used in two different multiplications doesn't mean that $\Psi^{-1}$ needs to be calculated twice. If you already computed the matrix $P = \Psi^{-1}$, then you could compute $a^TPa - b^TPb$ using the resulting matrix $P$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to rewrite the expression that you might like. We have
$$
a^T\Psi^{-1}a - b^T\Psi^{-1}b = \pmatrix{a & b} ^T \psi^{-1} \pmatrix{a & -b}.
$$